# ObjectTrackingEnabled and linq-to-sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I read [here](http://www.sidarok.com/web/blog/content/2008/05/02/10-tips-to-improve-your-linq-to-sql-application-performance.html) that when querying data for a read operation, setting `ObjectTrackingEnabled` to `false` gives somewhat of a performance boost. My queries look like this:

```
public return type TheQueryName (some parameters)
{
   using (TheDC MyDC = new TheDC())
   {
       var TheQuery = (...).ToList();

       return TheQuery;
   }
}
```

**1)** If I want to add the performance enhancement, do I just add the line `ObjectTrackingEnabled = true;` just before the line `var TheQuery = (...).ToList();`

**2)** Also, if I set `ObjectTrackingEnabled` to `true` in a query, do I need to set it to false before returning or am I just setting `ObjectTrackingEnabled` for the particular instance of the data context and the following time I'll instantiate a new data context the value of `ObjectTrackingEnabled`  will revert back to its default state of `false`?

**Note: I only plan do add `ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;` to read operations.**

Thanks.

Comment: This is another useful blog post about how things can get CRAZY out of control if you're unnecessarily tracking things : https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/dec/21/gotcha-entity-framework-gets-slow-in-long-iteration-loops

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ObjectTrackingEnabled controls whether your Data Context (`TheDC` in your case) will track changes to the entities after they're loaded. Whether you want that or not depends on your specific case.

Naturally, having the Data context do fewer things will make it go faster, but at the expense of burdening *you* with tracking changes. Why is change tracking cool? Because you can:

1. Load up some entities from some context
2. Modify them
3. Add new ones, delete others
4. Call `SaveChanges` and let the data context figure out to do UPDATE queries for modified entities, DELETE for deleted ones, etc

With change tracking disabled, you have to tell the context explicitly what changed, what the new values are, etc.

Assuming you still don't want object tracking, the property is set on each specific data context instance. This means you have to either:

1. Set it manually for every data context you create
2. Set it as a default for the context in the context's constructor like so: `this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;` See [this blog post](http://www.shujaat.net/2012/03/entity-framework-code-first-change.html) for details

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm only going to set ObjectTrackingEnabled to false for read operations. And as far as the syntax goes, can you see the question on point 1)?

Comment: Regarding where to disable change tracking, I'd do it as soon as I create the context. So, in your case, before the query, right after the `using` statement

Answer (score 3):

Your tags and subject line say 'Linq2SQL' but your question is about Entity Framwork.

For 'traditional' Linq2SQL you need this instead:

```
 linq2SqlDBContext.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Simon_Weaver, AFAIK "DataContext" is the correct term in L2S; EF started out w/ "ObjectContext", then added and moved to "DbContext". Also, L2S offers ObjectTrackingEnabled; see, e.g.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-retrieve-information-as-read-only

Comment: That's what I get for using 3 different MS 'datacontext' generations at the same time :-/

Answer (score 3):

In reference to:

1) If I want to add the performance enhancement, do I just add the line `ObjectTrackingEnabled = true; just before the line var TheQuery = (...).ToList();`

The query performance enhance comes from NOT tracking. 
So you want to disable this feature on `READ` queries, right after the new datacontext is created for this purpose.

```
ObjectTrackingEnabled = FALSE
```