# Does LINQ-to-SQL always return the same object reference for the same row and data context?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I did a quick test in LINQPad, and was pleasantly surprised to see that retrieving the same row with the same data context multiple times returns the same object reference:

```
var p1 = Products.Single(x => x.ProductID == 1);
var p2 = Products.Single(x => x.ProductID == 1); // this does not query
ReferenceEquals(p1, p2).Dump(); // True

// Run more complicated query, and dig through result rows to get the same row.
var result =
   (from d in OrderDetails
    select new { OrderDetail = d, Product = d.Product }
   ).ToArray();
var p3 = result.Select(r => r.Product).First(x => x.ProductID == 1);
ReferenceEquals(p1, p3).Dump(); // True
```

Is this guaranteed behavior?  Does LINQ-to-SQL always intern objects it retrieves, or is it possible to have subsequent queries return different objects for the same data?

Comment: Apparently this is supported, but can be controlled by the [ObjectTrackingEnabled option on the data context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021013/objecttrackingenabled-and-linq-to-sql).  More info about [object identity in LINQ to SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399376%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).